# Assigning N jobs to M people evenly, where N>>M

Tags: algorithm

I have the following assignment problem:

I want to assign N jobs to M people (with more jobs than people), in such a way everyone gets about the same jobs.
Suppose everyone has given their availablity for each of the jobs, is there an algorithm that I can use in this situation?

I've tried algorithms like Ford-Fulkerson's, but that leaves me with N-M jobs unassigned.

Comment: I have some doubts about your question, so u want to assign n jobs to m people and jobs are more so there will be n-m unassigned jobs...so obviously u won't be able to assign those left over jobs to anyone as all the people are occupied or the case is one person can be assigned more than one job, is it the case here ?

Comment: Yes, the latter one. People can be assigned more than one job. And I want the assignment such that all people get (approximatly) the same amount of jobs.

Comment: Got it and are u looking for anything specific in time complexity or you just want a working solution right now ?

Comment: I mostly want a working solution. Time efficiency has a lower priority.

Comment: Cool, I will try to work on something then, do you have an example input that you could provide me with and will it be ohk if I code this in c++ ?

Comment: Yes, https://pastebin.com/rhqDXXyK
Some jobs are already assigned, the first column says to who the job already is assigned to. The other columns (1:, .. ,11:) are the availibity for all the jobs. 

I, myself, am not really familiar with c++.

Comment: So in the above example, there are 115 jobs and 11 people right ?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: By just going through the job list, and assigning the jobs to the person with the lowest amount of jobs (so far), I found the solution found at https://pastebin.com/qEV10sgc

Comment: Ohh this is like a simple greedy technique that u used to assign the likely job to a person with least amount of work, that also sounds like a good solution, u don't need any special algorithm like Ford Fulkerson etc..

Comment: How big is N,M? What is your definition of *about the same jobs* (e.g. l1-norm of x_i - average vs. l2-norm of x_i - average)? Then of course: heuristic vs. approximation vs. exact-solution?

Comment: In the example above there are N=115 jobs, of which some already are assigined. M=11 people. To test 'about the same' I look at the square root mean squared error, sq[(x_i- M\N)^2]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you try to solve this with the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem. You immediately find that you have more jobs than people. Pretend that you have k copies of each person, for some small k. You may then have kM > N. In this case create dummy jobs that anybody can do to make kM > N (If kM < N you can't solve the problem as an assignment problem, so you need another k).

If the assignment problem finds a solution, then you have an assignment of people to jobs - and each person has no more than k jobs assigned to them. So if you find the smallest k for which the problem can be solved, you have a fairly even assignment - the assignment which gives the busiest person as few jobs as possible.

If you binary chop to find the smallest value of k you will need to solve the assignment problem about log(k) times. Each such problem has kM people versus kM jobs, and the cost of solving the assignment problem is about O(n^3) so this might be expensive, but if it turns out that kM is not much bigger than N this might be tractable.